# MAMP not connecting to localhost, any solutions?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, localhost, port, mamp

I have downloaded the newest MAMP version (3.0.5) and I am unable to connect to the localhost. All I get in Google is "Oops! Google Chrome could not find localhost:8888". I have tried all these things...

- Re-downloaded MAMP several times and restarted comp
- Changed the ports to 80 & 3306
- Turned Firewall on and off and added "MAMP" as an incoming connection
- Turned Web Sharing on and off
- Checked and unchecked options in MAMP Preferences and hit ok/restart

Is there any solutions out there that have worked for you? I know it all varies, but anything to get this going would be a miracle at this point.

Thank you!

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I was also experiencing the same issue on my OS X 10.9.4 with MAMP Pro 3.0.5 installed. The fix was very easy: missing info in my hosts file.

Solution found on: http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=82253

Note - I am using Mountain Lion

1) check your host file

- go to folder /etc/

File path is: Your-hard-drive:private:etc:hosts

- this is an invisible folder so you will need something that allows you to view invisible files folders on your Mac. I have Pathfinder installed which allows me to do this.
- there should be an entry that makes localhost work

For me there was nothing in the hosts file. It was blank

2) Drag it to the desktop, that'll copy it

3) Paste the following into it and save it:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

4) Then delete the one in the etc folder (it'll ask for your password)

5) Then move the copy into the etc folder (password again)

6) Then open terminal and paste this in:

sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
(It will require your password)

7) I needed to restart my computer and then MAMP started working again!
MampGuy

Comment: I had a load of old Adobe domains I deleted that helped too in the hosts folder.